# How to find out why a switch case loops infinitely?

Tags: c#

I use the following switch case to read different types of input, and whenever I reach a semicolon the output just loops infinitely (semi colon detected ;). One solution I found for something like this suggested checking input again after all the cases and I already do that in my code. I can't determine why it is looping and getting stuck on a semicolon.

```
     while (inputType != 0) 
    {
        switch (inputType)
        {
            case 1: // alpha
                {
                } // end case 1

            case 3: // numeric
                {
                } // end case 3

            case 5: // delimeter
                {
                    break;
                } // end case 5

            case 6: // space
                {
                    readChar(ref sentenceIX, ref sentence, ref inputChar, ref inputType);

                    if (inputType == 6)
                    {                                
                        readChar(ref sentenceIX, ref sentence, ref inputChar, ref inputType);
                        MessageBox.Show("Space detected " +inputChar);
                    } // end if
                    break;
                } //end case 6

            case 7: // semi colon
                {
                    readChar(ref sentenceIX, ref sentence, ref inputChar, ref inputType);
                    if (inputType == 7)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Semi Colon detected  " +semiColonChar);
                        readChar(ref sentenceIX, ref sentence, ref inputChar, ref inputType);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {

                    break;
                }
        } // end switch

    } //end while
```

I have also tried making the case 6 and 7 "if" instead of "while" and no change. I use a textbox for the string and I suspect it may be not letting go of the final char (;) in the string, and if so how would I make it do so?

Comment: We don't need all of your code... please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (emphasis on *minimal in this case)

Comment: To answer the question in your title, use the debugger

Comment: debugger is your best friend...

Comment: I think the `readChar` returns the last character over and over.

Comment: Yes, after trying a few things it seems like the readChar is returning the last character over and over. Not sure how to make it release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch` doesn't loop - `while` loops - nothing ever sets `inputType` to 0 so it loops infinitely

if you indend the `break` statements within the switch to break the `while` loop then add a state variable:"

```
bool _break = false; 
while (!_break && inputType != 0) 
{
    ...
        case 5: // delimeter
            {
                _break = true;
                break;
            } // end case 5

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, the problem with this is that it won't read any lines after the first since it will stop after it reaches the semicolon at end of the first line.